# An upper bound of gradient norm for convex functions near minimizer

Tags: convex-geometry, convex-optimization, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a convex function. Denote $X^*$ as the set of minimizers of $f$ and assume $X^*$ is unbounded. Is it possible that $\|g_x\|$ is unbounded when $d(x,X^*)$ is bounded where $g_x\in\partial f(x)$. Here $\partial f(x)$ denotes the set of subgradient vectors of $f$ at $x$ and $d(x,X^*)$ denotes the distance between point $x$ and set $X^*$.

---

I know $X^*$ is a closed convex set and I am thinking whether it is true that $\|g_x\|$ is bounded given $d(x,X^*)=1$. It must be true if $X^*$ is bounded, but not sure when it is unbounded. Also, does it help if we further assume $f$ is differentiable, so that $\partial f(x)=\{\nabla f(x)\}$?

---

**Edit**: I realized that what I really want to ask is whether it is possible that $\|g_x\|$ is unbounded but $d(x,X^*)$ is bounded. It is not equivalent to the boundedness of the ratio of $\|g_x\|$ and $d(x,X^*)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $q$ might be unbounded even in 1-neighborhood of $X^*$; here is an example of such function $f$ on the $(x,y)$-plane.

Let $\phi(t)=|t|-t$.
Choose a sequence $x_n\to \infty$.
For each $n$ consider function $f_n(x,y)=\phi[-2\cdot x_n\cdot(x-x_n)+ (y-x_n^2)]$.
Let $f=\max_n\{f_n\}$.

Comment: So by saying "the answer is no", you mean for your example, it is possible that $d(x,X^*)=1$ but $\|g_x\|$ is unbounded? or you mean it is not possible that $q(x)$ is unbounded? If it is the second case, then you need to prove $q(x)$ is bounded for any example $f$ right?

Comment: By the way, is It possible to also have a counterexample when subgradient reduces to gradient?

Comment: @JeanLegall, in the constructed example, $q$ is unbounded, and "yes" you can make such example smooth with unbounded $q$ in $1$-nbhd from $X^*$. (Use a smoothed version of $\phi$ and  sum instead of max.)

Answer (score 2):

Take the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x,y)=y^4$. Then $X^*$ is the $x$ axis, $dist(\;(x,y), X^*)= |y|$, $\Vert \nabla f(x,y)\Vert =4|y|^3$. $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$ $\newcommand{\ve}{{\varepsilon}}$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I actually want is the case when $dist(x,X^*)$ is bounded but $\nabla f(x)$ unbounded. However, for the current statement of the question, your example also works.

Comment: I will try to sketch a plausibility argument in favor of your guess.